# while clicking the upload button, got Error: Permission denied to access property "isFinished"

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-adf

I have added document.domain("test.com") in my page which is oracle adf, then clicking the import button and i got the below error in browser console log.

```
 Error: Permission denied to access property "isFinished"
<script>window.opener.isFinished='true'; window.close();</script>
```

So, its blocking the javascript method window.open(url); and not able to proceed next page.
Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet that you are using?

Comment: [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain) is not a function, its a string

Comment: yes.. i given document.domain="test.com".

Comment: <script language='javascript'>document.domain ="mydomain.com";
</script>

Comment: i shared the below code snippet .. please help on this

Answer (score 0):

```
         code snippet    
  function openNewWindow4Import(){
         var selectGroup=document.getElementsByName('importContactRadio');
   var selected='';
   if(selectGroup!=null && selectGroup.length>0){
         for(var i=0; i<selectGroup.length; i++){
            var selectElement = selectGroup[i];
             if(selectElement!=null && selectElement.checked){
                selected = selectElement.value;
                break;
             }            
        }       
   }
   var consumerName='';
   var noSelectRadioErrorArea = $('#' + 'mainTemplate\\:content\\:noSelectRadioErrorArea'); 
  if(selected==null||selected==''){
    noSelectRadioErrorArea.show();
    return;
  }
  noSelectRadioErrorArea.hide();
  var consumerNameArray = selected.split(':');
  if(consumerNameArray!=null && consumerNameArray.length>0){
    consumerName = consumerNameArray[consumerNameArray.length-1];
  }         
 if(consumerName =="google"){
        openwindow("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/GetContactServlet?consumer=google","import contact from google",900,600); 
  }
 if(consumerName =="yahoo"){
        openwindow("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/GetContactServlet?consumer=yahoo","import contact from google",900,600); 
  }
if(consumerName == "msn"){
        openwindow("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/GetContactServlet?consumer=msn","import contact from google",900,600); 

 }
if(consumerName == "outLook"){
    return;
 }
  waitForNavigateNextPage();

                                                         }                                                                   
 function waitForNavigateNextPage(){ if(childWindow.closed){
             var isFinish = window.isFinished;
             if(isFinish!=null && isFinish=='true'){
              window.isFinished='false';
                window.focus();
                 var continueButtion=document.getElementById('mainTemplate:content:continueButton');
                continueButtion.click();
                 clearTimeout(timeId);
                 return;
             }else{
                clearTimeout(timeId);
                return;
             }
 }
timeId = setTimeout("waitForNavigateNextPage()",1000);
```

}